# Javascript document.addEventListener is only working for 1 keycode

Tags: javascript

I have a simple program, and this is just a snippet.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("paper");

    var player = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var background = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var platform = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var backgroundColor = "rgb(140, 75, 2)";

    var platformColor = "rgb(60, 20, 123)";
    var platformDistFromTop = 120;
    var platformThickness = .5;

    //This is where the walking skins are stored.
    var playerWalkSkins = [
        "Drawing (1).png", "Drawing (2).png",
        "Drawing (3).png", "Drawing (4).png", 
        "Drawing (5).png", "Drawing (6).png",           
        "Drawing (7).png", "Drawing (8).png",
        "Drawing (9).png", "Drawing (10).png", 
        "Drawing (11).png", "Drawing (12).png"
    ]

    var playerXPos = canvas.width / 2;
    var playerYPos = platformDistFromTop;
    var playerSpeed = 4;
    var currentSkin = 0;

    var playerImg = new Image();


    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {

        if (event.keyCode == 37) { //left arrow

            playerXPos -= playerSpeed;
            if (currentSkin == playerWalkSkins.length-1) {
                currentSkin = 0;
        }
        else {
            currentSkin++;
        }
    }

    else if (event.keycode == 39) { //right arrow

        playerXPos += playerSpeed;
        if (currentSkin == playerWalkSkins.length-1) {
            currentSkin = 0;
        }
        else {
            currentSkin++;
        }
    }

    }, false);



    //Animation zone
    setInterval(function() {
        background.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
        background.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        platform.fillStyle = platformColor;
        platform.fillRect(0, platformDistFromTop, canvas.width, platformThickness);

        playerImg.src = playerWalkSkins[currentSkin];
        player.drawImage(playerImg, playerXPos, platformDistFromTop-57, 60, 60);
    }, 5);
}
```

The problem probably lies with the event lister. I have made other programs, with the event listener working, and I do not see any difference. The left arrow is the one that is working.

Thank you for any help, and I hope that I can continue my project.

Comment: Are you *sure* there's no error on the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your that your second `event.keycode` should read `event.keyCode` - the case matters in Javascript objects. Let me know if you are still stuck or need any help.

Comment: Lol! Too bad that the browser compiler did not catch it. I wonder why. Too bad I cannot delete questions. Whoops. 8p

Comment: No problem, at least you know you're only defeated by something totally obsecure and easy to miss. This is a good question to have on stack, so you shouldn't delete it, someone else probably will run into the same issue at some point. If you're happy with the fix, an accepted answer would be much appreciated. Thanks!